# Visualize manifold from the metric and extrinsic curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Is there some software or technique that would allow me to visualize a (2 dimensional) Riemannian manifold given its metric tensor and second fundamental form?

For instance, given
$$ g =d\theta^2 +\sin(\theta)^2 d\varphi^2$$
and
$$ K_{ab} \sim \begin{pmatrix}
a^2 & 0 \\
0 & \sin(\theta)^2
\end{pmatrix}$$

it would plot some oblong $\mathbb{S}^2$ type object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes There is.
Please visit
[Reconstructing a Surface from its Fundamental Form Coefficients](https://de.maplesoft.com/Applications/Detail.aspx?id=1344).
Just note that the result comes by numerically solving differential equations and the file comes in Maple software format.